# Memory issue with areg

Tags: memory, stata

I'm trying to regress a model with group-time fixed effects, and many dummies.

```
egen id_t = concat(id year), format(%15.0f)
areg y u2j* j2j* d1* d2* x1 x2, absorb(id_t) vce(r)
```

`d1` and `d2` are  dummies, for each there is hundreds of possible values. `u2j*` is the interaction of one variable, `u2j`, with time dummies:

```
forvalues t=1980/2000 {
    gen y_`t' = (year==`t')
    gen u2jXy`t' = y_`t'*u2j
    (...)
```

I'm running into a memory error trying to do this. All my dummies have size int, and all other variables are as small as they can be. What else can I try to resolve the memory issue?

The memory error, as I remember it, was

> You tried to allocate 8xxxxm of memory (256m through...), but your system administrator has set max memory to 80g. See help memory

Comment: Please post your **exact** error.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Unfortunately, that's in a center with high privacy regulation where I can't easily get data/text/errors out of. as I recall it, it was something along the lines of "tried to address 96... memory, but your system administrator has set the maximum to 80g"

Comment: What did you learn from `help memory`? What did you try afterwards?

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I learned that there was most likely nothing I can do. I guess the memory error comes from inverting the variance-covariance matrix. I was hoping that there was a slower alternative that doesn't rely on writing the whole var-cov matrix into the memory, but I suppose I was wrong. As I wrote in the question, I checked the data type of my variables, which are already at the minimum. Nothing else came to mind.

Comment: You can save some memory by `egen id_t = group(id year), label`. It won't be enough.

Comment: Cross-posted http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149227/memory-problem-with-areg Please don't cross-post on SE sites. The comments made there by @whuber appear cogent to me.

Answer (score 2):

if you have too many dummy variables, you should look for alternative estimation techniques that are specifically designed for that.

I would suggest reghdfe by sergio correa. look here

https://github.com/sergiocorreia/reghdfe

Its very efficient for high dimentional fixed effect problems. You should not run into any memory problems anymore.